# How to use repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions in Java

Tags: java, sorting, apache-spark, partition

Can anyone give a clear example on how to use repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions in Java, not scala.

Thanks in advance!!
Ani

Answer (score 2):

Take `JavaPairRDD<K, V>`:

```
JavaPairRDD<K, V> rdd = ...;
```

Define partitioner:

```
Partitioner partitioner = ...;
```

Optionally define `Comparator<K>` if needed.

```
Comparator<K> comparator = ...;
```

Apply method:

```
JavaPairRDD<K, V> repartitioned =
  rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner);
```

or

```
JavaPairRDD<K, V> repartitioned =
  rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner, comparator);
```